# Provide a operator== for std::variant

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, c++17, stdmap, std-variant

I am trying to create an `operator==`  operator for an `std::variant` defined in the map like this:

```
struct anyType 
{
   template<typename T>
   void operator()(T t) const { std::cout << t; }
   void operator()(const std::string& s) const { std::cout << '\"' << s << '\"'; }
};

template<typename T>
bool operator==(const std::variant<float, int, bool, std::string>& v, const& T t) 
{
   return v == t;
}

int main()
{
   std::map<std::string, std::variant<float, int, bool, std::string>> kwargs;
   kwargs["interface"] = "linear"s;
   kwargs["flag"] = true;
   kwargs["height"] = 5;
   kwargs["length"] = 6;
   //test 
   if (kwarg["interface"] == "linear") // stack overflow Error here 
   { 
      std::cout << true << '\n';
   }
   else
   {
      std::cout << false << '\n';
   }
}
```

Can someone tell me why my operator isn't working?

Comment: Your `operator==` does nothing but call itself recursively

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of issues in your code:

- `const &T t` in your `operator==`, should be `T const& t` or `const T& t`.
- You have forgotten to mention that you want to compare with a
  `std::string` not with `char` array in your if statement(i.e. `"linear"`). Meaning you
  need either of the followings:

  ```
  if (kwargs["interface"] == std::string{ "linear" })
  // or 
  using namespace std::string_literals;
  if (kwargs["interface"] == "linear"s)  // since C++14
  ```
- When you do the comparison like this

  ```
  if (kwargs["interface"] == "linear") // checking std::variant == char [7]
  ```

  You are checking the `std::variant<float, int, bool, std::string>`(i.e. `v`) with type `char [7]`(i.e. type of `linear`).
  When the condition reaches the `operator==`'s definition you do again
  the same by

  ```
  return v == t; // checking std::variant == char [7]
  ```

  This leads to a recursive call to the templated `operator==` itself
  and hence stack overflow.

---

In order to fix, you need**strong text** to explicitly specify the value from the variant either by index or by type. For example, chacking the type using [`std::is_same`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) and [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if):

**([See live online](https://godbolt.org/z/jWHkoz))**

```
#include <type_traits> std::is_same_v

template<typename T>
bool operator==(const std::variant<float, int, bool, std::string>& v, T const& t)
{
   if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, float>)            // float    
      return std::get<float>(v) == t;        
   else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>)         // int
      return std::get<int>(v) == t;
   else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, bool>)        // boolean
      return std::get<bool>(v) == t;
   else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>) // std::string
      return std::get<std::string>(v) == t;
}
```

or simply (*Credits [@Barry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2069064/barry)*)

```
template<typename T>
bool operator==(const std::variant<float, int, bool, std::string>& v, T const& t)
{
   return std::get<T>(v) == t;
}
```

Now if you pass any other types other than `v` contains, you will get a compile-time error for the templated `operator==`.

---

### Generic Solution!

For a generic `std::varaint<Types...>`, one can do as follows. In addition, it has been ***[SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae)*** d for only those types which are in the passed `std::variant<Types>`. I have used the [`is_one_of` trait from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62578701/divorce-a-parameter-pack-in-a-class-template/62578803#62578803).

**([See Live Online](https://godbolt.org/z/ZysJ9x))**

```
#include <variant>
#include <type_traits>

// A trait to check that T is one of 'Types...'
template <typename T, typename...Types>
struct is_one_of final : std::disjunction<std::is_same<T, Types>...> {};

template<typename... Types, typename T>
auto operator==(const std::variant<Types...>& v, T const& t) noexcept
   -> std::enable_if_t<is_one_of<T, Types...>::value, bool>
{
   return std::get<T>(v) == t;
}
```

Comment: The nested if constexpr/get chains just boil down to `return std::get<T>(v) == t;`